# How do I add streamlit caching to an imported function?

Tags: streamlit

I am using streamlit to build some data-centric user facing applications, and it is essentail to use caching to improve performance.

For example

```py
@st.cache_data
def load_data():
    return pd.read_csv('gcp://some-bucket/some-big-file.csv')
```

My issue is that defining these cached functions in my streamlit `app.py` file is getting out of hand and it's definitely time to define these in auxiliary `utils.py` or `loading.py` or `app_setup.py` files.

However, it's not obvious the best way to cache these imported functions.

Currently this is what I'm doing:

```py
from loading import load_data as _load_data

@st.cache_data
def load_data():
    return _load_data()
```

which at least turn long function definitions into 1-liners.

An alternative that also seems to work is:

```py
from loading import load_data as _load_data

load_data = st.cache_data(_load_data) # I don't love this, but I guess it works
```

Just wondering if any *streamlit power-users* have figured out what's the best pattern for this task.

Comment: From what I've seen, most folks use the first option you shared